# Should I flag questions where no research was shown?

Tags: discussion, flags

1. What should I do when someone simply asks us to do something for him without showing any research?
2. What if I have commented to a user on his answer that this should be a comment, not answer and subsequently that user starts to downvote me? When I asked the reason for the downvote, the answer was - remove your downvote on my question and I will do the same for your answer. Proof: [Is it possible to get information from this type of url: website.com/hello/richard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109227/is-it-possible-to-get-information-from-this-type-of-url-website-com-hello-richa/12109295#12109295)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the second question. The user seems to indicate he can no longer undo his downvote (after the window has expired). All he is asking is for you to edit your answer so he is allowed to undo his downvote again. I don't see anything problematic there.

Comment: Yes, I have misunderstood, that's why asked. What about first paragraph?

Answer (score 5):

With regards to your first question:
The downvote tooltip says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. So if there has been no research on behalf of the OP, that seems to fit perfectly fine.

If the question is truly problematic and would fall under the "Not a real question", "Too localized", "Off topic" or "Not constructive" headers, you could flag as any of those. But I don't know if that's the case here.

On a personal note: Whenever I vote to close something, I usually don't add an answer of my own. It feels a bit like "Yeah, your question should not be around, but I'll take all the rep I can get anyway". But that is entirely personal.

With regards to your second question:
The user merely seems to indicate that he wants to undo his downvote, but can't do so because the time-window has expired. All he asks you to do is make a trivial edit, so he is allowed again to undo his downvote. Nothing bad here. I have even abused my editing priviliges on an instance in the past just to be able to undo my mistaken downvote. But let's keep that between us and don't tell anybody else. ;)