# How to flag questions that show no research or code

Tags: discussion, flags

When reviewing low quality posts this question appeared https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4418249 . The question shows no research and no code that has been tried by the asker.

I want to recommend that the post be deleted, but with what reason? The post is, in my opinion, "off topic" as it asks for a solution but not help on a piece of code. None of the "off topic" options seem relevant.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144889/should-i-flag-questions-where-no-research-was-shown) seems relevant. Its answer recommends flagging with "This question does not show any research effort ..." but no such flag option is available to me.

Comment: Don't you have an option like *it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* in the off-topic reason?

Comment: @hims056 There is such an option but I think it is a poor choice. The question is perfectly clear, the asker wants some code written. If they see that as a response they may add some more details but their question will still probably boil down to "please write some code for me". There is nothing in the response to guide the asker unless they follow the MCVE link, but even that does not start with words about showing code and research.

Comment: custom, with reason "This question does not show any research effort ..."

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I would be happy with that, but I cannot see any "custom" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Too broad** 
>   There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to
>   narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a
>   few paragraphs.

Doesn't sound like they have isolated the issue if they're done no research or started to write any code. 
"How do I do this?" isn't a specific issue.

Comment: Agree with what you say, but that does not really prompt the asker to show their code or other research.

Comment: @AdrianHHH If you think that is an issue post a comment on the question saying so and then flag it as too broad.